# How can we load translations using api calls instead of having them defined in static jsons? How can this be done in React-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

On using internationalization in React application, Need to load the language translation files on demand using api calls and not have them defined upfront. How can this be achieved by using React-i18next?

Tried out the normal translations being picked from static predefined files using React-i18next. Tried using xhr-backend but unable to find any sample to implement this requirement of on-demand load of translation related data.

Comment: i18next provides plugin where you can load translation file from file system. e.g. [fs-backend](https://github.com/sallar/i18next-sync-fs-backend)

Comment: I am looking to load the translations json on demand received as a response from an api call, not using the file system. Something like the below link for react-intl https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/examples/async/index.jsx

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Do you mean you will receive the whole translation json from an API call? There are several plugins that support it, e.g. fetch backend

Comment: Yes. I want to receive my translation.json from an api call on demand when the user changes language manually. Any sample code or reference for this would help. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils) is a list of plugin you can choose from. The [fetch backend](https://github.com/perrin4869/i18next-fetch-backend) or the [xhr backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend) seem to suit your use case. You can find some examples from the links to their github page.

Answer (score 8):

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import axiosInstance from './helpers/Axios';

const loadResources=async(locale:string)=> {
    return await axiosInstance().get('/translate-data/get', { params: { lang: locale } })
      .then((response) => { return response.data })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
}

const backendOptions = {
  loadPath: '{{lng}}|{{ns}}', 
  request: (options:any, url:any, payload:any, callback:any) => {
    try {
      const [lng] = url.split('|');
      loadResources(lng).then((response) => {
        callback(null, {
          data: response,
          status: 200, 
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      callback(null, {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  },
};

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(backend)
  .init({
    backend: backendOptions,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,
    load:"languageOnly",
    ns: ["translations"],
    defaultNS: "translations",
    keySeparator: false, 
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, 
      formatSeparator: ","
    },
    react: {
      wait: true
    }
});

export default i18n;
```

Request from backend options is used to call backend API using Axios.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to load the .json file from a different domain? In your example, i don't see an external URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';


var language = i18next.language ||'en-US';


const backendOptions = {
  type: 'backend',

  crossDomain: false,

  allowMultiLoading: false,

  loadPath: `your-backend-api/?locale_code=${language}`

}

const options = {

  interpolation: {

    escapeValue: false, // not needed for react!!

  },

  initImmediate: false ,


  debug: true,    


  lng: language,


  fallbackLng: language,


  // have a common namespace used around the full app

  ns: ['translations'],

  defaultNS: 'translations',


  react: {
    wait: false,

    bindI18n: 'languageChanged loaded',

    bindStore: 'added removed',

    nsMode: 'default',

    defaultTransParent: 'div',

  },
};



options['backend'] = backendOptions;

i18next
  .use(XHR)
  .init(options)


export default i18next;
```

Comment: how to switch language for this code when we want to call api using laguage code