# i18next Get Languages from REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, i18next

I created a Next Js project and i used i18next library in this project. After I created REST API using PHP.

It worked as static for me. But I should get all languages from REST API. How can i do this?
I've been dealing with this problem for 2 days and couldn't find any resources. All I want to do is to include the languages ​​I will pull from the REST API into my Next project.

I need a source/roadmap.

Thank you.
Best regards

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748722/how-can-we-load-translations-using-api-calls-instead-of-having-them-defined-in-s but I don't get it to work.
I got i18next to call my backend with correct lang parameter, the backend sends the exact json as i had previous in my static file. But i18next doesn't use that data.

Comment: how did you resolve this issue Susat?